# failed to compile : unexpected parsing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> JSX fragment elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag.

Because I already use enclosing what's the problem?

Trades.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Trades extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="card bg-dark text-white">
                Card Title
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
                <p className="card=text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="/#" className="card-link">Card link</a>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        exchange: exchangeSelector(state)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Trades)
```

[image]
Content.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { exchangeSelector } from '../store/selectors'
import { loadAllOrders } from '../store/interactions'
import Trades from './Trades'

class Content extends Component { 
  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadBlockchainData(this.props.dispatch)
  }
 async loadBlockchainData(dispatch) {
    await loadAllOrders(this.props.exchange, dispatch)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      ......
          <div className="card bg-dark text-white">
            <div className="card-header">
              Card Title
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
              <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
              <a href="/#" className="card-link">Card link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="vertical">
        <Trades />                              // <<--
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    exchange: exchangeSelector(state)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Content)
```

Comment: first fragment: you're returning two "top-level" elements in that `return` statement `<div>...</div><div>...</div>` ... second fragment: you've hidden some of it with '......' so who knows

Comment: There are extra </div> tags, remove them.

Comment: you have <Trades />

Comment: @DarkKnight - perfectly valid

Comment: @Bravo i'm just joking hehe XD.

Comment: The error message even tells you how to fix that first problem ... enclose the returned value in `<>  </>` - exactly those 5 characters is all you need

Comment: @DarkKnight - damn, I only just figured out the joke .... didn't make the connection between the two code fragments :p

Comment: i m so thank you for all reply ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you are returning two elements in Trades component.

you have to return one element in component.
 so instead of

```
 <div className="card bg-dark text-white">
            Card Title
  </div>
   <div className="card-body">
            <p className="card=text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="/#" className="card-link">Card link</a>
   </div>
```

try this:

```
  <>
        <div className="card bg-dark text-white">
            Card Title
        </div>
        <div className="card-body">
            <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="/#" className="card-link">Card link</a>
        </div>
    </>
```

more info in react docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax

Comment: thank you for reply   
I didn't know so many people would answer

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in your class name `card-text`, you are mispelling it as `card=text`, and use enclosing tags when defining a react component, here:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Trades extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="card bg-dark text-white">
                    Card Title
                </div>
                <div className="card-body">
                    <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="/#" className="card-link">Card link</a>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        exchange: exchangeSelector(state)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Trades)
```

Comment: ALso if that was all, your should vote to close as typo type instead of answering

Comment: how about using `<>...</>` instead of `<div>...</div>` - like the error message in the OP's post suggests?

Comment: @Bravo use whatever you want as far as its enclosing tag, i guess its dealer's choice, I prefer divs :)

Comment: @Learner - using divs adds markup that could effect CSS and other things ... using `<>...</>` means no extra markup (that empty tag isn't going to end up in the DOM)

Comment: @Bravo fine :) I usually use div in my scripts as they give me more feel like HTML, but you are right, when dealing with a third person script, you dont know how their styling is defined and where the component is used so its better to use the empty tags, modified the answer

Comment: @Learner - thank you for seeing it my way :p you are indeed a good learner (messing with you, all good)

Comment: @Bravo Thanks and bravo ;)

Comment: @HyeongwonO no problemos, happy to help, you can express your gratitute by upvoting answers, leave mine without any upvote as I anyway have enough reputation and also credit goes to Bravo for helping me correcting my answer but upvote other users answers who have low reputation and invested their time to help you

Answer (score 1):

The issue in code is, in **return** method you are sending two tags or siblings, while in **React** you must have single parent which can be divided into multiple children.

Your code :

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className="card bg-dark text-white">
                Card Title
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
                <p className="card=text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="/#" className="card-link">Card link</a>
            </div>

        )
    }
```

After wrapping two **div's** in one parent **div**, new code

```
    render() {
            return (
               <div>
                  <div className="card bg-dark text-white">
                      Card Title
                  </div>
                  <div className="card-body">
                      <p className="card=text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="/#" className="card-link">Card link</a>
                  </div>
               </div>

            )
        }
```

Comment: thank you for reply   
I didn't know so many people would answer